# URL Manipulation PHP

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, apache

I have a url something like

```
http://something.com/abc/def/file.php/arguments
```

This simply executes final.php and /arguments is passed to $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] variable.

I want to execute the same but without the '.php' i.e,

```
http://something.com/abc/def/file/arguments
```

I am guessing I need to add something to http.conf, or...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.htaccess is your friend

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule file/(.*) file.php?param=$1
```

Comment: I had to modify this to my needs. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do this is to adopt the MVC style url manipulation with the URI and not the params.

In your htaccess use like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #Rewrite the URI if there is no file or folder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then in your PHP Script you want to develop a small class to read the URI and split it into segments such as

```
class URI
{
   var $uri;
   var $segments = array();

   function __construct()
   {
      $this->uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
      $this->segments = explode('/',$this->uri);
   }

   function getSegment($id,$default = false)
   {
      $id = (int)($id - 1); //if you type 1 then it needs to be 0 as arrays are zerobased
      return isset($this->segments[$id]) ? $this->segments[$id] : $default;
   }
}
```

Use like

http://mysite.com/posts/22/robert-pitt-shows-mvc-style-uri-access

```
$Uri = new URI();

echo $Uri->getSegment(1); //Would return 'posts'
echo $Uri->getSegment(2); //Would return '22';
echo $Uri->getSegment(3); //Would return 'robert-pitt-shows-mvc-style-uri-access'
echo $Uri->getSegment(4); //Would return a boolean of false
echo $Uri->getSegment(5,'fallback if not set'); //Would return 'fallback if not set'
```

Now in MVC There usually like http://site.com/controller/method/param but in a non MVC Style application you can do http://site.com/action/sub-action/param

Hope this helps you move forward with your application.

Comment: +1 Although I don't think the MVC design pattern has anything to do with URL rewriting.

Comment: thanks for your blazing fast response.  But, I have the code base, I just need to make my question working, any suggestions on what has to be added in htaccess?

Comment: Its the Url pattern used for CMP (Controller/Method/Params)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to rewrite your URL's. Have a look here: http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

Answer (score 0):

This URL style can be managed by the `url_rewrite` (called url rewriting) and it can be done with `.htaccess` file of your `Apache` server.

to do it you'll need to write this in you `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^http://something.com/every/name/you/like/(arguments)/?$    server_folder/page.php?argument_var=$1
```

The first block of code, rapresents the user called page:

```
^http://something.com/every/name/you/like/(arguments)/?$
```

The second block is the real page you want to call, where `$1` is the var value inside the `()`

```
server_folder/page.php?argument_var=$1
```

If the user must go to an `URL` where the arguments are numbers only you should insert:

```
^http://something.com/every/name/you/like/([0-9])/?$
```

If the user must go to an `URL` where the arguments are letters only you should insert:

```
^http://something.com/every/name/you/like/([a-zA-Z])/?$
```

To work correctly with this URL style you'll need to understand a little bit of regular expresions like **[in this link](http://www.patricktaylor.com/mod_rewrite-hideindex)**.

You could find useful **[this table](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/)** to help you understand something more.

Note you can write different URL instead of the real page name like:

```
^http://something.com/love/([a-zA-Z0-9])/?$    section/love/search.php?$1
```

This should be useful to hide server pages.